# Unable to add physical volume '/dev/hda' to volume group

Tags: lvm

I'm trying to create a volume group for my docker lvm but get errors.

```
prem@prem-ubuntu:~/ba/docker-lvm-plugin$ sudo vgcreate volume_group_one /dev/hda
  Device /dev/hda not found (or ignored by filtering).
```

How do you create a device that is not available? Am I allowed to create a device?

Comment: The process should be `physical volume --> volume group --> logical volume`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating physical volume in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/935089/creating-physical-volume-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The steps are:

```
   -- create partitions on disk drives (type 8e in fdsik)
   -- create physical volumes from the partitions                  --> $ sudo pvcreate /dev/sda1
   -- create the volumes group                                     --> $ sudo vgcreate -s 16m vg /dev/sda1
   -- allocate logical volumes from the volume group               --> $ sudo lvcreate -l 50g -n mylvm vg
   -- format the logical volumes                                   --> $ sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/vg/mylvm
   -- mount the logical volumes (also update /etc/fstab as needed) --> $ mkdir /mylvm, 
                                                              then --> $ sudo mount /dev/vg/mylvm /mylvm, 
                                                          then add --> /dev/vg/mylvm /mylvm ext4 defaults 0 0 ( to the /etc/fstab)
```

General Structure:

```
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  |                                                         LVM                                               |
  |                       ------------------------------------------------------------------------------|     |
  |         FILE SYSTEMS  |          /HOME(EXT3)              ||                /DATA(XFS)              |     |
  |                       |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|     |
  |  LOGICAL VOLUMES(LV)  | /DEV/PRIMARY_VG/HOME_|V           ||      /DEV/PRIMARY_VG/DATA_|V           |     |
  |                       |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|     |
  |   VOLUME GROUPS(VG)   |                           PRIMARY_VG                                        |     |
  |                       |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|     |
  |   PHYSICAL VOLUMES    | /DEV/Sdb1   ||   /DEV/Sdb2        ||     /DEV/Sdc1     ||   /DEV/Sdc2       |     |
  |                       |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|     |
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|

     PARTITIONS           |---------------||-------------|              |----------------||-------------------|
                          | /DEV/Sdb1     || /DEV/Sdb2   |              |  /DEV/Sdc1     ||   /DEV/Sdc2       |
                          |---------------||-------------|              |----------------||-------------------|
                          |------------------------------|              |-------------------------------------|
    PHYSICAL DRIVES       |             /Dev/Sdb         |              |                /Dev/Sdc             |
                          |------------------------------|              |-------------------------------------|
```

Comment: Your welcome, please accept the answer if it helped you. :)